# CSS whole page vertical and horizontal align

Tags: html, css

Since 4k monitors are nascent, I need to align a small page from all four sides of the monitor. It consists of absolutely positioned divs, which are placed inside a container.
The body:

```
 <div id="mainArea">
    div elements containing text, images, links go here.


    </div>
```

The css:

```
body {

background-image: url();


}
```

.mainArea {

```
position: absolute;

width: 882px; 

height: 420px;

left: 50%; top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

I've tried a number of suggestions on the internet, but they basically solve horizontal and vertical alignment for simple content, like text or images, not for the whole website. These somehow do not work in my case, perhaps due to my inexperience. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Your CSS looks like it should work as long as there are no other positioned elements that are ancestors of `mainArea`. Perhaps the problem is that your have written `.mainArea` in your CSS, which would select elements with the *class* mainArea, but your HTML has mainArea as an *ID*. Your CSS should say `#mainArea` to reference the element with that ID.

Comment: The original psot should have had # instead of . I changed it here on stackoverflow because it was shown in a big font in relation to the rest of the code. This is why i've decided to change.

Now, this give me the following look - http://alsem.lv/index_de2.php

Comment: Give this a look :) https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/ (Vertical Centering – Solved by Flexbox – Cleaner, hack-free CSS)

Comment: hhmm. Doesn't work - http://alsem.lv/index_de4.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc`:

```
position: absolute;

width: 882px; 

height: 420px;

left: calc((100vw - 882px ) / 2);
top: calc((100vh - 420px ) / 2);

transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Update. The following seemed to work:

.cn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

.inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 width: 1246px;
 height: 810px;
}

Output - http://alsem.lv/index_de4.php
I've checked the view using different resolutins on http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//alsem.lv/index_de4.php&w=1920&h=1080&a=4

It shows well on bigger screens, but this method fails on smartphones and tablets, eating out space atop. Any suggestions?